# I do not know how to set up this probability question.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a seven digit code would be assigned only odd digits, in any order, and digits cannot be repeated?

Comment: There are not enough odd digits to select seven without repetition.

Answer (score 1):

For the first number, there are five possibilities: $1, 3, 5, 7, $ or $9$.  For the second number, there are only *four* possibilities, since you are not allowed to repeat the number which is in the first position.  For the third number, there are again four possibilities, since you are not allowed to repeat the number which is in the second position.  There are similarly four possibilities for the fourth, fifth, sixth, and seventh numbers.  The total number of possibilities is then:
$$5 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 20480.$$